# unshorten urls for a large dataset in python 3.x, socket.gaierror, getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, url, python-requests, urllib

Using python 3.6 on windows 10, I'm trying to evaluate a column of urls.
I have a csv file with a column of urls. Some of them are shortened.urls. You could create a csv file with one column for these urls if yuo want to reproduce results:

```
external_urls
http##://rviv.ly/NdL..
http##://rviv.ly/kDH..
http##://rviv.ly/GA7..
http##://rviv.ly/zCZ...
http##://rviv.ly/46HW...
http://bit####ly/2GzanWa # replace the '###' with '.' Links to https://www.careerarc.com/job-search/linquest-corporation-jobs.html?listing_not_found=true
https##://www.sec.gov/news/press-release/2018-41
```

My actual table is very large with around 100000+ urls to evaluate. The following code seems to crash inconsistently (will verify this, but I swear that last night I was getting different lines for failure). It gives the error below

Error traceback:

```
\lib\socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

My code

```
 import http.client
 from urllib.parse import urlparse
 print("calculating most frequent url domains")
 df = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_Hq_CSV)
 clean_url_lst = []
 domain_lst = []
 domain_dict = {}
 for urls_ in df['external_url']:
    print(urls_)
    if str(urls_) == "nan":
        continue
    else:
        o = unshorten_url(str(urls_))
        print("URL: \t", str(o)) # still prints the shortened url

def unshorten_url(url):
   parsed = urlparse(url)
   h = http.client.HTTPConnection(parsed.netloc)
   h.request('HEAD', parsed.path) # error traces to this line
   response = h.getresponse()
   if response.status/100 == 3 and response.getheader('Location'):
     return response.getheader('Location')
   else:
     return url
```

What does this error mean?

I think unless I can get a general workaround for this error, I won't be able to unshorten urls in python 3.

Comment: Maybe you should put a try-except block and see which url is causing the error. To be honest, it will take a lot of time to resolve that number of URLs.

Comment: I added a try-except block and also adjusted my code so that it uses the requests package as mentioned in one of the other answers.
So I'm clearly seeing the time issues... It is a lot of urls.

I think the best i can do is create a program that sets a timer for a few seconds to evaluate how long the  `requests.get(url)` call takes. if a requests.get call takes too long, then I can add that row to a list of skipped rows and try to process them later?

Comment: Or you can just divide the whole set of URLs into multiple subsets, then process them in parallel. It can be done using multiple threads, or if you have multiple machines, it could be better.

Comment: I've worked with multithreading only a couple of times and usually in C and C++ rather than Python so I was trying to avoid it...  am going to look up guides but is there any quick tips you can give to someone who really has never used multithreading in python?
The instructions here seem clear. Create subsets of my url and then allow each via multithreading.... would that mean each thread gets a subset, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the [requests package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

```
import requests
url = 'http://fb.com'
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
except Exception as e:
    print('Bad url {url}. {e}'.format(url=url, e=e))


print(response.url)
print([redirect.url for redirect in response.history])

"""
# Output
>> https://www.facebook.com/ 
>> ['http://fb.com/', 'https://fb.com/']

"""
```

Comment: I changed my code however, you still end up getting the previously mentioned error out of nowhere at times, `socket.gaierror getaddrinfo failed`. It would really help if someone could tell me what this error message means.

Comment: that url must be invalid. Put it in your browser and see what happens. see my update